# Why does Samsung Internet perform poorly compared to other mobile browsers?

Tags: samsung-internet-browser

I'm experiencing performance issues on my e-commerce website, particularly on Android devices. When analyzing loading times, I've noticed that Samsung Internet takes about 2.5 times longer to load compared to Chrome and Safari.

Given that Samsung Internet is based on the Chromium project, I was surprised by this inferior performance. I would like to understand the possible reasons behind this. Could it be due to memory management, differences in JavaScript compilation, or other unknown factors?

If anyone can provide information or tips on how to improve performance on Samsung Internet, it would be greatly appreciated for enhancing the user experience on our website.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that website development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of your queries, developer-side solutions are out of the scope of this community. For development questions, you might want to try our sister site [so].